# Using Nokogiri with multiple search elements

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

In this XML snippet I need to replace the data in the UID for some of the blocks. The actual file contains more than 100 similar blocks.

Although I have been able to extract subsets based on `name="Track (Timeline)"`, I am struggling to reduce this subset to the specific block I need by also using the data in the `<TrackID>`, if `name="Track (TimeLine)"` and the text of `<TrackID>` is `0x1200` then set `UID` to xxxx.

I am new to Nokogiri and, although I write test scripts, I do not consider myself a programmer.

```
<StructuralMetadata key="06.0E.2B.34.02.53.01.01.0D.01.01.01.01.01.3B.00" length="116" name="Track (TimeLine)">
    <EditRate>25/1</EditRate>
    <Origin>0</Origin>
    <Sequence>32-04-25-67-E7-A7-86-4A-9B-28-53-6F-66-74-65-6C</Sequence>
    <TrackID>0x1200</TrackID>
    <TrackName>Softel VBI Data</TrackName>
    <TrackNumber>0x17010101</TrackNumber>
    <UID>34-C1-B9-B9-5F-07-A4-4E-8F-F4-53-6F-66-74-65-6C</UID>
</StructuralMetadata>
<StructuralMetadata key="06.0E.2B.34.02.53.01.01.0D.01.01.01.01.01.3B.00" length="116" name="Track (TimeLine)">
    <EditRate>25/1</EditRate>
    <Origin>0</Origin>
    <Sequence>35-12-2D-86-E6-74-0B-4C-B4-24-53-6F-66-74-65-6C</Sequence>
    <TrackID>0x1300</TrackID>
    <TrackName>Softel VBI Data</TrackName>
    <TrackNumber>0x0</TrackNumber>
    <UID>37-0C-80-34-4C-8D-CE-41-85-F3-53-6F-66-74-65-6C</UID>
</StructuralMetadata>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using xpath:

```
//StructuralMetadata
```

will select all `StructuralMetadata` elements in your XML. The double slash at the start means to select nodes wherever they appear in the document.

You don't want *all* the nodes though, you can filter the ones you want with a predicate:

```
//StructuralMetadata[@name="Track (TimeLine)" and TrackID="0x1200"]
```

This will select all `StructuralMetadata` elements that have a `name` attribute with the value `Track (TimeLine)`, and a `TrackID` child element with contents `0x1200`.

As you're interested in the `UID` element, you can further refine the expression:

```
//StructuralMetadata[@name="Track (TimeLine)" and TrackID="0x1200"]/UID
```

This expression will match all the `UID` elements that are children of `StructuralMetadata` elements that match the predicate described above.

Putting this to use:

```
require 'nokogiri'

# Parse the document, assuming xml_file is a File object containing the XML
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_file)

# I'm assuming there is only one element in the document that matches
# the criteria, so I'm using at_xpath
node = doc.at_xpath('//StructuralMetadata[@name="Track (TimeLine)" and TrackID="0x1200"]/UID')

# At this point, doc contains a representation of the xml, and node points to
# the UID node within that representation. We can update the contents of
# this node
node.content = 'XXX'

# Now write out the updated XML. This just writes it to standard output,
# you could write it to a file or elsewhere if needed
puts doc.to_xml
```

Comment: I like this. XPath is a good way to do it, if you're going to be using XML much it's certainly worth learning.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Think this is the way to go - guess I'm going to have learn more about xpath.

Answer (score 1):

A great way to approach this problem is with the ‘map reduce’ style of programming, which works to take a large list of things and narrow it down and combine it into the result you're after. Specifically, `Array#find` and `Array#select` are really useful for this sort of problem. Check out this example:

```
require 'nokogiri'
xml = Nokogiri::XML.parse(File.read "sample.xml")
element = xml.css('StructuralMetadata').find { |item|
  item['name'] == "Track (TimeLine)" and item.css('TrackID').text == "0x1200"
}
puts element.to_xml
```

This little program first uses the CSS selector to get all of the `<StructuralMetadata>` elements in the document. It returns an array, which we can filter to just what we want using the `Array#find` method. `Array#select` is its cousin which returns an array of all the matching objects instead of the first one it happens to find.

Inside the block we have a test to check if the `<StructuralMetadata>` tag is the one we’re after. Then it puts the `element.to_xml` string to the console so you can see which thing it found if you run this as a command-line script. Now you can find the element, you can modify it in the usual way and save out a new XML file or whatever.

Comment: This way you actually ignore the XPath or CSS search functionality of Nokogiri and throw all data to `.find`. Why not solve the "narrowing" with Nokogiri?

Comment: Thanks blixxy - that does the job for me

Comment: @karatedog Trevor said they don't consider themselves a programmer, which makes me think they're a beginner learning ruby. Best to get moderately good at one language before delving in to new languages like xpath and css selectors, regexps, and other languages in general. I think it's important to keep things really simple and clear when first starting out learning this stuff. As a sidenote, I don't think this problem could have been solved with a CSS selector, could it? Xpath sure. :)